# Unordered list items adding space underneath images

Tags: html, css, horizontal-scrolling

Not sure if the title is the real issue, but my horizontally scrolled list of images is not playing nice. I want all the images to bunch up (effectively float) next to one another (which I've managed to achieve using `display:inline` thus far). But I want them to all be 100% height of the window/body, and it isn't playing nice.

Here's my HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="content">
    <ul id="content-images">
        <li>
            <img src="image1.jpg"/>
        </li>
            <li>
            <img src="image2.jpg"/>
        </li>
            <li>
            <img src="image3.jpg"/>
        </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

And the CSS:

```
html, body{

    margin:0px;
    border:0px;
    padding:0px;

    height:100%;

}

#content{

    height:100%;
    background-color:green;

}

#content-images{

    height:100%;

  white-space: nowrap;

}

#content-images li{

    font-size:0;
    display:inline;

    height:100%;

}

#content-images img{

    max-height:100%;
    height:auto;
    max-width:100%;
    width:auto;

}
```

The problem is a small gap of about 2/3px that runs along the bottom of the li items. It is hard to tell if it is part of the `body` or part of the `list items`, but either way it is an annoying anomaly.

I'm viewing in Chrome. I've attached a screenshot. Note the bottom white line. To be clear, I'm happy for the images to run off the page on the x-axis, and for the client to scroll horizontally through the images, but I don't want any gaps on the vertical, between the images and the edge of the window.

[image: Screenshot]

**Update:**

I'm unable to replicate the issue in jsFiddle because the fiddle seems to have difficulty with styling the `html`, `body` and relatively-sized images. I haven't got the time or pateince to figure out why.

I've decided to go for a hack. A mixture of `vertical-align:bottom` on the **img** and an `overflow-y:hidden` on the **html** and **body**. This will make any whitespace after the list items redundant, as the viewable area will be restricted.

Comment: Can you create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for your problem?

Comment: I take your point @Sourabh but unfortunately a jsFiddle doesn't seem to want to display the images at full size. Is this a jsFiddle issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prevent this using `vertical-align: bottom` on your image tag, like so:

```
img {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: As I had said to the commenter below my question, this doesn't solve the problem. It possibly shaves off a pixel, but there is still a white line underneath the unordered list.

Comment: He has since deleted his comment which is a shame.

Comment: I did not know as the comments are removed. Can you give us a jsfiddle that illustrates your problem so we can have a better look?

Comment: I've decided to give you the correct answer as yours was the closest contribution to my hack, outlined in my edited question.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting thing problem because of `display: inline` **[[Reason here](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)]**. Alqin is right, `float:left` will solve the problem, but you also have to remove `display:inline`. If you want horizontal slider, you can increase width of `ul` to sum of widths of images and use `overflow-x:hidden` or `overflow-x:auto` on its parent `div`.

PS: Its not a good idea to use `height:100%` on all elements. It will make your page look weird when the content overflows.

I changed the CSS to following, and also removed properties that I thought were unnecessary:

```
html, body{
    margin:0px;
    height:100%;
}

#content{
    height:100%; /* a bad idea */
    background-color:green; /* add this to body if you want whole body green */
    overflow-x: auto;
}

#content-images{
    height:100%; /* again, a bad idea*/
    width: 3000px; /* sum of widths of images I used to test */
}

#content-images li{
    font-size:0;
    float: left;
}

#content-images img{
    max-height:100%;
    height:auto;
    max-width:100%;
    width:auto;
}
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is the need to use a programming language to determine the size of the unordered list. I appreciate the time you've put into it but I would need to calculate the sum of the widths in JavaScript or on the server in PHP first. This is why I chose `inline` over `float`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the margin from the unordered list element?

```
#content-images{
    height:100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: I have applied 0 margin, padding and border to every element I can think of.

Comment: Try changing the li item display property to inline-block. You should be able to tell really quickly what element is creating the space below by inspecting the elements in the Chrome Dev tools.

Answer (score 0):

Use float left instead of inline:

```
#content-images li{

float:left;

}
```

That space is because inline elements have a space after them. Add an margin-bottom:-4px to images. Also give the images `display:block`. Play will all this, you should be able to fix your problem.